# Google Sheets Send SMS to a specific person based on status change of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sms

If you are reading my question, Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help.

Background:
I have a form that my field techs use in order to request parts, I would like to keep them updated on the status of a part order with an automated sms text to their phone.

Specifics:
Link to test Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hEDEk-3-z3Wh6PNLoY6PgmbSJZ7OcdMR0kFCl0BRrYU/edit?usp=sharing

[Parts Request (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEfD7.jpg)

- Status Change

When a Status is changed in (column G), this will trigger an SMS to be sent.

- Recipient
  The SMS will be sent to the Team Lead ( Column B) in that row.
  Example: Status is changed (G2), SMS is sent to Team Lead (B2).

[Employee Info (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygy1X.jpg)

Employee Information:
The Script pulls the Employee Telephone number(Employee Info! B2) from the Employee Info Sheet

Text Body:
The Message that is sent would be the entire row in the text message
-Team Lead
-Type of Request
-Job Name
-Part Description
-QTY Missing
-Status

The Script i have tried so far has been a simple one, based on a trigger of anytime a change is made to the sheet. Here is what i have used so far, this has worked and has been sending generic texts. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   function sendText() {
  var EmailTo = "'Mobile Number'"@txt.att.net";
  var subject = "Whatever";
  var body = "Text";

  MailApp.sendEmail(EmailTo, subject, body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The processes needed to achieve your goal involves fetching the desired details on the row wherein the status of the request changes, incorporating the given phone number to the appropriate carrier domain, and adding an installable trigger so that the script will automatically work when there are changes to the Status Column.

Here is the script:

```
function sendUpdates(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var shEmployeeInfo = ss.getSheetByName("Parts Request");
  var shPartsRequest = ss.getSheetByName("Employee Info");
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  if(column == 7) { //To limit checking of changes to the Status column
    var info = shEmployeeInfo.getRange(row, 2, 1, 6).getValues();
    var header = shEmployeeInfo.getRange(1, 2, 1, 6).getValues();
    var carrier = shPartsRequest.getRange(row,4).getValues();
    const subject = "Insert Subject Here."; //Edit this to change the subject
    const carrierMap = { "ATT": 'txt.att.net',
      "T-Mobile": 'tmomail.net',
      "Sprint": 'messaging.sprintpcs.com',
      "Verizon": 'vtext.com',
      "Cricket": 'mms.mycricket.com' }
    var phoneNumber = shPartsRequest.getRange(row,2).getValues();
    var emailTo = `${phoneNumber}@${carrierMap[carrier]}`;
    var body = "";
    for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      body += header[0][i] + ": " + info[0][i] + "\n";
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, body);
  }
}
```

The installable trigger should be set as:
[image]

Please refer to the [Installable Triggers Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for more information.

As for the result, I made a test case and got this:

[image]

Comment: Holy Smokes , thank you for your help in this, I am still very new and appreciate the opportunity to learn and expand my knowledge. I will put this in and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Hey, So I have pasted the code, and i am unable to get it to work. At first when i was running the sript from the editor i was getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined. I looked it up and from what i have read it cannot run, but has to have an event, so i understand that now. Yet still when testing from the sheet nothing happens? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there! You do not need to run the script, just save it. However, you need to add an installable trigger for it to run whenever there are changes on the spreadsheet. Please refer to this tutorial video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC7pBjD3GGw around 9:42 to learn how to add an installable trigger. With regards to the setup of the trigger, please follow the one I provided in my answer. I hope this helps.